# infinispan as second level cache hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, infinispan, second-level-cache

Trying to use infinispan as a second level cache for hibernate but always gives me the following error

> org.infinispan.jmx.JmxDomainConflictException: ISPN000034: There's
>   already a JMX MBean instance
>   type=CacheManager,name="DefaultCacheManager" already registered under
>   'org.infinispan' JMX domain. If you want to allow multiple instances
>   configured with same JMX domain enable 'allowDuplicateDomains'
>   attribute in 'globalJmxStatistics' config element     at
>   org.infinispan.jmx.JmxUtil.buildJmxDomain(JmxUtil.java:51)    at
>   org.infinispan.jmx.CacheManagerJmxRegistration.updateDomain(CacheManagerJmxRegistration.java:79)

and here is the hibernate properties

```
setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache", "true");
            setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_query_cache", "true");
            setProperty("hibernate.cache.region.factory_class",
             "org.hibernate.cache.infinispan.InfinispanRegionFactory");
            setProperty("hibernate.cache.infinispan.statistics", "false");
            setProperty("hibernate.cache.infinispan.cfg", "infinispan-config.xml");
```

the infinispan config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <infinispan xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:7.2"
    xsi:schemaLocation="urn:infinispan:config:7.2 
                        http://www.infinispan.org/schemas/infinispan-config-7.2.xsd
                       urn:infinispan:config:store:jdbc:7.2
                       http://www.infinispan.org/schemas/infinispan-cachestore-jpa-config-7.2.xsd">

    <cache-container default-cache="default" statistics="false">
    <local-cache name="simpleCache" statistics="false">
    </local-cache>

    </cache-container>
</infinispan>
```

I have two projects with two datasources , one for audit and the other is the main web project.
and the xml value that is in the exception doesn't exist in infinispan version 7.2 onward 
thanks in advance for any help :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add `<jmx duplicate-domains="true" />` to `<cache-container />`.

The error message should be updated.

Comment: Worked great , many thanks :) , but isn't that just a work around the main problem which is creating the JMX domain multiple times ?

Comment: Depends on your setup, and how you use JMX. You can set `<jmx domain="foo"/>` to view them in distinct domains.

Comment: guess I have to dive more inside the infinispan documentation to understand the correct configuration for the JMX , but according to them the defaults should work with no problems :(, but seems that is not the case.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative solution, where you are trying to get rid of xml configuraton files if needed. We can allow duplicate domains programmatically as well.

```
GlobalConfiguration config = new GlobalConfigurationBuilder()
                                .globalJmxStatistics()
                                .allowDuplicateDomains(Boolean.TRUE)
                                .build();
EmbeddedCacheManager cacheManager = new DefaultCacheManager(config);
```